# Why do I get error #1005 - Can't create table 'FinalProject.#sql-3875_a1' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to update my tables with constraints to allow my primary keys to transfer to the other tables in my database.... It doesn't happen that way. Here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE APPLICANT (
            Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            Email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            CompanyName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            Phone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            Fax VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            GovernmentEmployee BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            Academic BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            InternationalAttendee BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            Speaker BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            Presenter BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            FirstTimeAttendee BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (Name, Email)
);


CREATE TABLE TIME (
            TimeAnswer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            Email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (TimeAnswer, Name, Email)
);


CREATE TABLE DAY (
            DayAnswer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            Email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (DayAnswer, Name, Email)
 );


 CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
            Address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            ZIP NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,
            LocationName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            LocationEmail VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
            Country VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            City VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (Address, ZIP)
);


CREATE TABLE WORKSHOP_SESSIONS (
            Email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            WorkshopAnswer VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (Email, Name)
 );


 CREATE TABLE WORKSHOP_DAY_TIME (
            Email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            DayAnswer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            TimeAnswer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (Email, Name, DayAnswer, TimeAnswer)
 );


 ALTER TABLE WORKSHOP_SESSIONS ADD CONSTRAINT information_workshop_sessions_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (Email, Name)
 REFERENCES APPLICANT (Email, Name)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

 ALTER TABLE LOCATION ADD CONSTRAINT applicant_location_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (LocationEmail, LocationName)
 REFERENCES APPLICANT (Email, Name)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

 ALTER TABLE DAY ADD CONSTRAINT applicant_day_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (Email, Name)
 REFERENCES APPLICANT (Email, Name)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

 ALTER TABLE TIME ADD CONSTRAINT applicant_time_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (Name, Email)
 REFERENCES APPLICANT (Name, Email)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

 ALTER TABLE WORKSHOP_DAY_TIME ADD CONSTRAINT time_workshop_day_time_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (TimeAnswer)
 REFERENCES TIME (TimeAnswer)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

 ALTER TABLE WORKSHOP_DAY_TIME ADD CONSTRAINT day_workshop_day_time_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (DayAnswer)
 REFERENCES DAY (DayAnswer)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

  ALTER TABLE WORKSHOP_DAY_TIME ADD CONSTRAINT workshop_sessions_workshop_day_time_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (Email, Name)
  REFERENCES WORKSHOP_SESSIONS (Email, Name)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: ALL OF MY TABLES ARE CREATED IN MY DATABASE AND NOW I'M JUST TRYING TO ALTER THEM. IF THIS HELPS ANY.

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW ERRORS` ?

Comment: If you log in as root (I suppose it's your local MySQL server and you can do so) you can run the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` query. You'll find a "last foreign key error" section with the exact reason of the error.

Comment: This is what I get when I click on more details about the error;
 InnoDB  

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

All your tables work well.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2190/1)

Comment: I'm using this as a school project, and I have forms on a webpage posting data to the APPLICANT table, that updates, and then the other tables don't have anything.

Comment: in your title it saids cant create table `FinalProject` but you didnt give this table.

Comment: That's the name of my Database though, which is why i'm so unsure of what is going on.